# Determine if the sequence $b_n=(1+{3\over n})^n$ is convergent or divergent as $n\rightarrow \infty$. If the sequence converges, find its limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I'm trying to solve the problem that is in the title, but I cannot find an example in my book or in my notes that is like this. I'm stuck and don't know where to start.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that $$e:=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^n,$$ so $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{a}{n} \right)^{bn}=e^{ab},$$ in this particular case $$\left( 1+\frac{3}{n}\right)^n \to e^3$$ when $n \to \infty.$ So $(b_n)$ converges to $e^3$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Remmember the Fundamental Limt

$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)^x=e$$

Answer (score 2):

Expand the binomial.

$$\left(1+\frac 3n\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom n k \left(\frac 3 n\right)^k$$

Set $a_k=\binom n k \left(\frac 3 n\right)^k$. By writing out the binomial coefficient in terms of factorials and looking very closely at the resulting expression, prove that $a_k$ is strictly increasing and bounded by (in fact, converges to) $\frac {3^k} {k!}$. Conclude that $b_n$ is also strictly increasing and bounded by

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac {3^k} {k!}$$

Finally, prove (or perhaps recall from your course) that the above series converges, thus showing that $b_n$ is a strictly increasing and bounded sequence.